# Shiny how to process batch input data and return output in table?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm new to shiny. I'm trying to create a UI that allow user to paste in data in batch, do some calculation with the data and then return the result as a table, but I couldn't get the output table working here.

I've researched on textinput and shinyTable and end up choosing `tags$textarea` since this allow me to enter in batch. But I wasn't able to perform calculation with the input data and I'm not sure how to resolve this.

[image]

Code Snippets

**ui.R**

```
source("Assign Module.R")
tabPanel("Assign Module",
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel( "Property Locations",
                          helpText("Enter one address per line below"),
                          tags$style(type="text/css", 
                                     "textarea {width:100%}"),
                          tags$textarea('location', 
                                        placeholder = 'Paste here', 
                                        rows = 8, 
                                        ""),
                          br(),
                          actionButton("goButton", 
                                       "Go!")
            ),

            mainPanel(
              tableOutput('modules')
                      )

 ))
```

**server.R**

```
library(ggmap)
library(shiny)
  modules <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    geocode<-geocode(as.character(input$location))
    m<-getmodules(geocode)
    df<-cbind(input$location,m)
    return(df)
  })

  output$modules <- renderTable({
    modules()
  })
```

**Assign Module.R**

```
centers <- aggregate(cbind(data.t$Latitude,data.t$Longitude)~data.t$Cluster, FUN=mean)
n.cluster=nrow(centers)
R <- 3958.756 # Earth mean radius [miles]

radians = function(theta=0){return(theta * pi / 180)}   #convert to radians

dist <- function(xind, yind)    # Define the Grear Circle Distance function
  acos(sin(G[xind, 1]) * sin(C[yind, 1]) + 
         cos(G[xind, 1]) * cos(C[yind, 1]) * cos(C[yind, 2] - G[xind, 2])) * R

modules<-function(df){
  n.row=nrow(df)
  G <- radians(df[,c(2,1)])
  C <- radians(centers[,c(2,3)])    
  dist_mat<- outer(seq.int(n.row), seq.int(n.cluster), dist)
  modules <- apply(dist_mat,MARGIN=1,which.min)

  return(modules)
}
```

**sample input**

```
10 E. Delaware Place,   Chicago,    IL  60611
100 Arbor Court,    Wheeling,   IL  60090
100 Center Street,  Mishawaka,  IN  46544
100 Forest Avenue,  Oak Park,   IL  60301
1000 W. Washington Boulevard,   Chicago,    IL  60607
1000 Waukegan Rd.,  Deerfield,  IL  60015
1000-1010 N. Lake Shore Drive,  Chicago,    IL  60611
```

Please let me know if any information needed. Any help is appreciated!